# how to optimized long running query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

It takes high resources. i play concurrent some long running queries and server became down.
query is like

```
SELECT posts.id 
FROM posts 
WHERE postId = '765888827630161920' AND feedId = '3700' AND wallId = '949'
```

The table has over 100 000 rows.

Comment: Consider `indexing` columns which is used in `where` clause

Comment: Thankyou @Saurabh. i have already applied it....

Comment: What does 'count in lacs' mean? Perhaps 'count in lakhs'? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

Comment: yes it means Lakhs.

Comment: Just make it simple and easy to understand for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a composite index on your filter column

```
ALTER TABLE `posts ` ADD INDEX `idx_posts` (`postId `, `feedId`, `wallId` );
```

Comment: please let me know about idx_ prefix.

Comment: @MayankSharma   is only a my personal naming convention  .. normally i add a prefix (idx ) for index .. and for not have the same name  of the table or the columns

Comment: Thankyou it works for me..it have little speedup my query.

Answer (score 0):

The first step for optimize a query is using EXPLAIN.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT posts.id 
FROM posts 
WHERE postId = '765888827630161920' AND feedId = '3700' AND wallId = '949'
```

This SQL offer the way MySQL obtain the data.

The first solution without see the result of EXPLAIN is add an index to each field you using in where conditions

```
CREATE INDEX index_postId
ON posts (postId)
```

The same for feedId and wallId.

The use of index increment the size of table but increase the speed MySQL search in the data.

Answer (score 0):

In your query:

```
SELECT posts.id 
FROM posts 
WHERE postId = '765888827630161920' AND feedId = '3700' AND wallId = '949'
```

`postId` should be unique in the table `posts`. This is a reasonable assumption, given the names. So this query should be sufficient:

```
SELECT id 
FROM posts 
WHERE postId = '765888827630161920'
```

And according to you you have indexed postId... so that's the most optimal query possible.

Makes me wonder why there's a `postId` and an `id` in the table `posts`???

If you have very many posts, many milions, you could put older post in a different table, or even a different database or server, because most of the time only the latest post will be needed.

Comment: id is primary key and postId is id which is getting from third party api.

Comment: So, is `postId` unique? Why not call it something more sensible like: `thirdPartyId` or `originalId`, anything else than `postId`? Remember that your code should, in principle, be comprehensible by other programmers, even if, at the moment, you're the only one working on it.